# How can i diassemble a D .obj file under Windows?

Tags: d

How can i diassemble a `.obj` file from the D-compiler?

I am using windows so i can't use the microsoft `objdump` because the format is different.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities to do this

---

**Without paying money**

Go to [objconv](http://www.agner.org/optimize/#objconv) and download the archive and unpack it.

You can then use `objconv -fyasm file1.obj file1.asm` to diassemble the file.

In the archiveis also a PDF file which explains other command arguments for this tool.

---

**With paying money**

Go to [link](http://www.digitalmars.com/ctg/obj2asm.html) and pay for it.

Comment: Third option is to produce COFF object files on x64 Windows and use Microsoft tool stack.

Answer (score 1):

.obj files produced by dmd on Windows can also be disassembled, still on Windows, in [IDA free](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/download_freeware.shtml).

Note that It also works for .lib files.